# Alternating and special orthogonal groups which are simple

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, simple-groups

I have an idle curiosity about a funny coincidence between two sequences of groups.  It is well-known by those who know it well that the alternating group $A_d$ of degree $d$ is simple if and only if $d\not\in\{1,2,4\}$.  By what seems like an astonishing coincidence to me, the special orthogonal group $SO(d,\mathbb{R})$ is simple if and only if $d\not\in\{1,2,4\}$.  Is this merely a coincidence?

Comment: Seems like the strong law of small numbers to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers . The fact that $A_3$ is simple is essentially an accident (it's too small not to be simple).

Comment: I love "It is well-known by those who know it well" :-)

Comment: Well, there is an [informal principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) saying that $A_d$ is $SO(d;\mathbb F_1)$...

Comment: How are $A_1$ and $A_2$ not simple?  Aren't they trivial?